# How to hide an existing attribute in one tab and show it in the other tab

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Hybris backoffice OOTB configuration comes with this attribute "last changes" shown in the administration tab  as show below.

[image]

I have a requirement where I need to move the same attribute to the "history" tab as you can see above.
I have made the following changes to bring that attribute based on the code below

```
<context merge-by="type" parent="GenericItem" type="Product" component="editor-area" module="pcmbackoffice"
             principal="backofficeadministratorrole,merchandisergroup,digitalmerchandisergroup,marketplacemanagergroup">
        <editorArea:editorArea xmlns:editorArea="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/editorArea">
            <editorArea:tab name="hmc.tab.product.change.logs" position="32" displayEssentialSectionIfPresent="false" merge-mode="merge">
                <editorArea:section name="hmc.tab.product.change.logs">
                    <editorArea:attribute qualifier="SavedValues"
                                          editor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.defaultmultireferenceeditor"  merge-mode="merge">
                        <editorArea:editor-parameter>
                            <editorArea:name>readOnly</editorArea:name>
                            <editorArea:value>true</editorArea:value>
                        </editorArea:editor-parameter>
                    </editorArea:attribute>
                </editorArea:section>
            </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
    </context>
```

An the atribute appears fine in the history tab as below

[image]

Question:

I want to hide / remove the attribute "last changes" from the administration tab.How can I do that ? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
<context  parent="GenericItem" type="Product" component="editor-area">
    <editorArea:editorArea xmlns:editorArea="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/editorArea">
        <editorArea:tab name="hmc.administration">
            <editorArea:section name="hmc.section.saved.values" merge-mode="remove" >
                <editorArea:attribute qualifier="SavedValues" merge-mode="remove"/>
            </editorArea:section>
        </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
</context>
```